# .htaccess getting wrong giving 500 internal error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to convert my link like this:

from `http://example.com/pictures.php?title=new`
to
`http://example.com/new`.

Here is my `.htaccess`; it's giving me a 500 internal server error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /pictures.php?title=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c> 
   # Turn off mod_security filtering. 
   SecFilterEngine Off 

   # The below probably isn't needed, 
   # but better safe than sorry. 
   SecFilterScanPOST Off 
</IfModule>
```

What's wrong in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid rewrtiing actual files like `.js, .css and images` to `pictures.php`. Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /pictures.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your rewrite may be causing a loop. A `RewriteCond` to avoid a loop is usually a good idea;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/pictures.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /pictures.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this simply

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /pictures.php?title=$1 [L]
```